# Calcular metas de caixa PHP

Tags: php, matemática

Olá, como eu poderia fazer calculo de meta de caixa com PHP? Tenho um query na qual retorna todos as entradas do mês atual e em seguida as soma.

Meta: 200000.00
Total obtido até agora: 15000.00

Como eu poderia pegar a porcentagem de concluído?

Comment: pctConcluido = TotalObtido / Meta * 100

Comment: Valeu, haha, era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem segredo, você irá armazenar o retorno da sua query em uma variável

`$total = resultado_da_query;`

Dividir pela meta e multiplicar por 100.

`$meta = 200000;`

`$porcentagemDoMes = ($total / $meta) * 100`;

Caso você queira exibir o resultado pode fazer:

`echo $porcentagemDoMes . "%";`

Ou você pode incapsular isso numa função e colocar o retorno da função:

`return $porcentagemDoMes . "%"`;

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!